# Вытащить значение в квадратных скобках

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Как вытащить из строки значение в квадратных скобках?

```php
$firstStr = "[35231] Text text text text (text text text) text text";
```

Я так понимаю регуляркой? Но у меня тяжело с этим.
Нашел похоже что мне нужно, вроде работает, но есть сомнения, может как то проще можно? Подскажите пожалуйста

```php
preg_match('/\[(.+?)\]/', $firstStr, $matches);
echo $matches["1"];
//35231
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у Вас `[35231]` всегда в начале, то можете добавить `^`.
Если в фигурных скобках подразумевается только число, то вместо точки используйте `\d`.

```php
$firstStr = "[35231] Text text text text (text text text) text text";

//Если в фигурных скобках всегда число
preg_match("/^\[(\d+?)\]/", $firstStr, $matches);

//Если в фигурных скобках любые символы
preg_match("/^\[(.+?)\]/i", $firstStr, $matches);

echo $matches[1];
```

Если нужно искать несколько вхождений, то используйте `preg_match_all`

```php
$firstStr = "Text text [35231] text text (text text text) text [15215]";

preg_match_all("/\[(\d+?)\]/", $firstStr, $matches);

echo "<br>" . $matches[1][0]; // Будет содержать 35231
echo "<br>" . $matches[1][1]; // Будет содержать 15215
```

Comment: А зачем вам хвост в виде `.*`?

Comment: @Visman В принципе незачем. Поправил.

Comment: Второй предложенный вами вариант испытайте на строке `[35231] Text text text text (text text text) text [text]` ;)

Comment: А нужен ли тут символ ^ ???

Comment: @Visman Спасибо за комментарии. Вернул `?` для ленивой квантификации.

Comment: А нужен ли тут символ ^ ???  $firstStr = "Батарейка [35231] AAA Duracell (LR03-4BL TURBO)"; Так работать уже не будет.  Хотя скобки всегда будут в начале строки , но тем не менее

Comment: @Agapkin Мы не знаем точного контекста. В ответе я написал условие, когда ставить `^`

Comment: А результат всегда искать в $matches с ключом 1 ??? Других вариантов тут быть не может?

Comment: @Agapkin Если Вам нужно несколько вхождений `[число]`, то нужно использовать `preg_match_all `

Comment: @Agapkin В $matches c ключом 0 содержится найденная подстрока `[число]`. Для того, чтобы взять только число, которое содержится в квадратных скобках, используются круглые скобки для группировки. Кол-во элементов в $matches зависит от кол-ва групп. Т.к. в данном случае у Вас только одна группа, то и содержится она, соответственно, в элементе с ключом 1.